# iOS Firestore IsPersistenceEnabled does not disable existing cached listener results

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

The cache routinely fulfills our first FireStore snapshot listener results, almost always with out-of-date data (obviously). The listener often fires again with the missing results immediately after.

Using FireStore settings to set isPersistenceEnabled to false does not stop cache results from returning. Do I have to clear the cache that has already been built?

When checking snap.metadata.isFromCache, the cache is clearly still operating.

Disabling persistence while the VC is being embedded in present does nothing (Container View):

```
vc?.db = Firestore.firestore()
let settings = FirestoreSettings()
settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false
vc?.db?.settings = settings
```

Some code:

```
var isFirstQuery = true
queuesInLocationRef?.remove()
queuesInLocationRef = db?.collection("location").whereField("city", isEqualTo: city).whereField("region", isEqualTo: region).addSnapshotListener({ (snapshot, error) in
    guard let snap = snapshot else {
         print("watch location err: ", error!)
         return
    }
    self.processDocumentChanges(documentChanges: snap.documentChanges, isFirstQuery: isFirstQuery)
    isFirstQuery = false
})
```

I have important things to do the first time the listener fires. When I have an internet connection, this will often fire with stale cached results first, which I want to exclude. I have tried checking isFromCache and early returning, but have found that even with a network connection, up-to-date results may come back as from the cache. This results in the listener not firing again.

If cached results never came back, it would be smooth sailing. I am not sure what disabling persistence does in the iOS SDK but it does not help here.

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.  Also be clear about exactly when you are calling the API to disable persistence.

Comment: Again, please be clear about when you called the API to disable persistence.

Comment: @DougStevenson is that clear enough? I call the API at an arbitrary time long before setting up a listener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is addressed by telling the SDK to deliver [events for metadata changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-metadata-changes).  Be sure to read that documentation thoroughly.

When you register for metadata changes, your callback will be invoked when something in the metadata changes, including the source of the data (even if the document data didn't change at all).  This is how you can check if the data is definitely up to date from the server - `snapshot.metadata.isFromCache` should return false.

To ask for metadata changes, call [addSnapshotListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Query#addsnapshotlistenerincludemetadatachanges:listener:) like this:

```
query.addSnapshotListener(includeMetadataChanges: true) { documentSnapshot, error in
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either limit the amount of memory available to Firestore's global cache or discard cached results on a per-return basis. It sounds like you just want to ignore cached results, so just ignore them:

```
guard let cached = snapshot?.metadata.isFromCache,
    !cached, // only pass guard when false
    let snapshot = snapshot else {
        return
}

// handle results
```

This is the same as writing:

```
if let cached = snapshot?.metadata.isFromCache,
    cached == false {
    // handle results
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with this approach is when the app is offline.  Offline apps get cached results if they are available.  If the cached results are ignored, the app will cease to work offline as you'd expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson and that is the caveat of ignoring cached results, you're right to point that out.

Comment: @bsod I have tried early returning, but sometimes the cloud results are the same as my cached results, and the listener never stops returning from cache. Do you mind sharing how to limit the cache size?

Comment: @RolfLocher sounds like you have some other issues going on. I would address those issues before limiting cache size. But this is how you'd do it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline#configure_cache_size

Comment: @bsod Is that not the expected behavior of the Firestore cache? I know a lot of services that tell users to use the cache even when there is a connection, so long as their cache is up-to-date with what is being requested.

Comment: @RolfLocher if the listener never stops returning from cache, meaning that it only returns from cache, that is definitely not expected behavior. I don't suspect that's what's really happening, though.

Comment: @liquid I am revisiting this question and answer almost two years later as the solution was never fully implemented and we were having the same issues. What I did not realize was from the documentation, for isFromCache, "Returns YES if the snapshot was created from cached data rather than guaranteed up-to-date server data. If your listener has opted into metadata updates (via `includeMetadataChanges:YES`) you will receive another snapshot with `isFromCache` equal to NO once the client has received up-to-date data from the backend". I needed includeMetadataChanges for the guaranteed "NO" update